# What tag should we use for questions about buying pets?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/384/48) question didn't have a tag for buying a pet; I've made an edit suggestion to add [adoption](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adoption). It seems relevant in this case, but *adoption* to me has the connotation of transferring ownership from one family to another, or perhaps adopting a rescue or a pet from a shelter.

Is there a better word we could use for buying pets from a young age, or is adoption suitable in all cases?

Answer (score 5):

I think [adoption](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adoption) is fine for all acquisitions, whether free, nominal cost (shelters), or purchases.

The issue of age is orthogonal; people both buy and otherwise adopt adult animals too, not just young ones.

Comment: It's been pointed out in chat that while this makes sense for assorted furry pets, people don't tend to think of "adopting" fish, lizards, crawfish, and the like.

Answer (score 4):

There is no wiki for [adoption](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adoption), but personally, I wonder if adoption should be more about the adoption process and not actually bringing a new pet home.

Maybe a new tag for new pets regardless of how the arrive like [new-pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-pets)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me.  If we have questions specifically about adoption then they're likely to end up tagged something like "ferals" or "animal-shelters" or the like, right?

Comment: `new-pets` could be the synonym and adoption could be a tag

Answer (score 3):

I think [adoption](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adoption) is good for, well, adopting from a shelter or a rescue or from another family, etc, but if the pet is coming from a pet store or breeder, you could also consider [purchasing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purchasing), perhaps?

I know a lot of people, myself included, don't always like the connotation of a pet being bought - the idea of an animal you are going to consider a companion being something you buy just like you buy toilet paper or dish soap or what have you is kind of awkward.

That said, I think the actual word will come down to personal preference, but having both [adoption](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adoption) and [purchasing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purchasing) might not be a bad thing, I don't think, as they can have two different connotations in people's minds like I mention in my first paragraph.

Comment: In what cases would you want to separate these?  When would somebody be interested in finding questions about only one type of pet acquisition?